# tratando de hacer un custom view en umbraco y me sale un [object object]

Tags: angularjs, objeto, umbraco

Tratando de hacer un custom view en umbraco (al inicio me funcionaba, estoy usando angular) y me sale un `[object object]`

Les comparto el custom view
en el archivo html, el title funciona, pero el description no.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="block.edit()" class="btn-reset umb-outline blockelement-labelblock-editor blockelement__draggable-element card-view">
    <div class="content-block-title card-view">
        <h2 class="card-h2" ng-bind-html="block.data.title"></h2>
        <p class="card-p" ng-bind-html="block.data.description"></p>
    </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Entre [las preguntas similares que ya se han hecho](/search?q=object+object+[javascript]+or+[angular]+is%3Aquestion), ¿alguna está relacionada a la tuya?

Comment: Hola. Esto es código de `angularjs', la etiqueta que pones es `angular 2` hacia arriba. No tienen nada que ver el uno con el otro.

Comment: @Legna se corrige la etiqueta y se agrega la etiqueta Umbraco